# Inscribing rectangles in circles

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

Please,

Can every rectangle (regardless its dimensions' lengths) be inscribed in a circle?

I mean that its 4 vertices must be on a circle...

Thanks

Comment: The diagonals cannot bisect nor be perpendicular on each other unless it's a square, right?

Comment: They are not perpendicular unless it's a square, but they do bisect. And they also have the same length, so you can conclude...

Comment: So, both diagonals can be diameters of the same circle, right?

Comment: Right. Now you can post an answer your own question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A circle can pass through any three non collinear points.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to  @EthanBolker and @Evargalo.

As a geometric property for a rectangle, its diagonals have the same length. As such, the diagonals can be diameters for one circle. Consequently, The 4 vertices of any rectangle can form one circle.

By the same reasoning, one can conclude that any quadrilateral whose diagonals are congruent can be inscribed in a circle.

Comment: Your last statement is, unfortunately, false.

Comment: @Aretino why? May you explain?

Comment: Here's an example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GuqN.png

Comment: @Aretino Then, the diagonals must bisect each other in order for the quadrilateral to be inscribed in a circle...

Comment: But if the diagonals of a quadrilateral are congruent and bisect each other, then that quadrilateral is a rectangle and the statement is obvious.